# Converting potentiometer value to string for GLCD display

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to display a potentiometer's value on an Adafruit ST7565 GLCD. My serial monitor is giving me values between 1.62-1.67, while the GLCD ranges from -20,000 to +20,000. I'm not sure whether the arithmetic/data type is wrong or whether I am allocating memory improperly for the "sprintf" conversion.

```
#include "ST7565.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

char buffer[5];
int ledPin =  13;    // LED connected to digital pin 13
char str[8];

// the LCD backlight is connected up to a pin so you can turn it on & off
#define BACKLIGHT_LED 10
// pin 9 - Serial data out (SID)
// pin 8 - Serial clock out (SCLK)
// pin 7 - Data/Command select (RS or A0)
// pin 6 - LCD reset (RST)
// pin 5 - LCD chip select (CS)
ST7565 glcd(9, 8, 7, 6, 5);

#define LOGO16_GLCD_HEIGHT 16 
#define LOGO16_GLCD_WIDTH  16 

void setup()   {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // turn on backlight
  pinMode(BACKLIGHT_LED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(BACKLIGHT_LED, HIGH);
  // initialize and set the contrast to 0x18
  glcd.begin(0x18);
  glcd.display(); // show splashscreen
  delay(3000);
  glcd.clear();
  Serial.println(" ");
  digitalWrite(BACKLIGHT_LED, HIGH);
  glcd.drawstring(0,0," ");
  glcd.display();
  glcd.clear();
}

void loop() {
  // read the input on analog pin 0:
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  // Convert the analog reading (which goes from 0 - 1023) to a voltage (0 - 5V):
  float voltage = sensorValue * (5.0 / 1023.0);
  // print out the value you read:
  Serial.println(voltage);
  digitalWrite(BACKLIGHT_LED, HIGH);
  Serial.println(voltage);
  sprintf(str,"%d",voltage); // converts to decimal base.
  glcd.drawstring(0,0,str);
  glcd.display();
  delay(500);
  glcd.clear();
}
```

Any insight is appreciated. I don't have much formal programming experience, so linking a tutorial about data types won't be of any use. I need to see a specific example like this worked out to truly understand.

Comment: `sprintf(str,"%d",voltage);` is wrong, `voltage` is not an `int`. Are you looking for `snprintf(str, sizeof str, "%d", voltage);` instead? (Also note the use of `snprintf()` for the sake of safety.)

Answer (score 0):

You used `%d` to print out a `float`; this is undefined behaviour (in your case, it probably dumped out the integer representation of some part of the `float`'s bit sequence).

Instead of using `sprintf` (since `sprintf(..., "%f", val)` is reportedly broken on Arduino), use [`dtostrf`](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdlib.html#ga060c998e77fb5fc0d3168b3ce8771d42):

```
dtostrf(voltage, 0, 2, buf);
```

Also, if you're interested, you can see how Arduino prints floats [here](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.cpp#L225).